# addEventListener if else condition not work

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I do not understand why the second condition does not work (else if inside function `changeText`).

When I click it changes my clickable1 and clickable2  together instead of treating each of my clicks separately.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<h1 id="clickable1"> Click me plz </h1>
<h2 id="clickable2"> Click me too plz </h2>
<script>
var text = ["thanks for clicking first", "thanks… but why only second?"];
var index = 0;
var indexId = 0;
document.getElementById("clickable1").addEventListener("click",changeText);
document.getElementById("clickable2").addEventListener("click",changeText);

function changeText(){
  if(document.getElementById("clickable1")){
    document.getElementById("clickable1").innerHTML = text[0];
  }
    else if(document.getElementById("clickable2")){
      document.getElementById("clickable2").innerHTML = text[1];
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't do `if(document.getElementById("clickable1")){ document.getElementById("clickable1").innerHTML = text[0];}` While searching for an ID isn't that bad, there's no reason to waste CPU effort here. Use a variable, something like: `var clickable1 = document.getElementById("clickable1"); if(clickable1){clickable1.innerHTML = text[0];}`

Answer (score 1):

You're second condition never runs because first condition is always true. You are checking for if there is an element in DOM with ID equal to `clickable1`. And that's always true. That's why it never enters in else if

What you can do is check the clicked element ID. Something like

```js
var text = ["thanks for clicking first", "thanks… but why only second?"];
var index = 0;
var indexId = 0;
document.getElementById("clickable1").addEventListener("click",changeText);
document.getElementById("clickable2").addEventListener("click",changeText);

function changeText(event){
  if(event.target.id === "clickable1"){
    document.getElementById("clickable1").innerHTML = text[0];
  }
    else if(event.target.id === "clickable2"){
      document.getElementById("clickable2").innerHTML = text[1];
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<h1 id="clickable1"> Click me plz </h1>
<h2 id="clickable2"> Click me too plz </h2>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, condition

```
if(document.getElementById("clickable2"))
```

just checks if exists a `DOM` element with `clickable2` id property.

One solution to your problem could be the passing of the **event** parameter to your function.

```
function changeText(event){
```

and then just use `event.target` property in order to find out the control which fires the `click` event handler.

Also, your code could be simplified by using a `ternary` operator:

```
function changeText(event){
     id = event.target.id
     document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = id == 'clickable1' ? text[0] : test[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The test `if (document.getElementById("clickable1"))` will:

1. Call `getElementById`
2. This will evaluate as either `null` (if the element doesn't exist) or the element (if it does).
3. Test to see if that is a true value (elements are, `null` is not).

Your test has nothing to do with determining which button was clicked on, only if it exists in the document.

`this` will be the element on which the event handler was attached, so you can compare that to the buttons…

```
if (document.getElementById("clickable1") === this){
```

Meanwhile, the event object will tell you what element was actually clicked, so you could do:

```
function changeText(evt){
    if (document.getElementById("clickable1") === evt.target)
```

… this approach is better when you are using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) as it lets you bind the event handler *once* to an element that is an ancestor of the elements that might be clicked on.

This is a more complicated approach though, and you have to account for situations such as:

```
<button> a <span>b</span> c </button>
```

… where a click on the `b` in the button would give you an event target of the `<span>` element.